# How do we call sonar from our java method.Sonar should return analysis report of our project as pdf document

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube

I have run jenkins, the build was successful and it gives below line on console:

```
ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/PROJ:DAM
```

How we can call the above url from our web application?

The above url relates to a sonar dashboard. Also, how can we get the report as a PDF?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the maven sonar pdf plugin as explained here: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE44/PDF+Plugin

After running the analysis, just trigger the generate goal on plugin to generate the pdf.

Comment: This plugin is deprecated and does not work with the current LTS version of SonarQube

Comment: I'm still running 4.x... so it does work for me. It would be *great* if you could answer the question for version 5+.

Comment: for this we need to go to sonar and download the pdf. i dont want this .i have an application, from my applicaiton i need to call sonar to get pdf by calling rest api.